# DFT in EmguCV not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, emgucv, dft

I'm programming in WPF(C#) using emgucv-windesktop 3.1.0.2282. I'm new in image processing and I want to use FFT and DFT in my image processing application. here is my code:

```
Image<Gray, System.Single> _image = new Image<Gray, System.Single>(
    Util.ImageSourceToBitmap(img1.Source));

UMat DFTimage = new UMat();
UMat Original = new UMat();

CvInvoke.Dft(_image.ToUMat(), DFTimage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Forward , -1);
CvInvoke.Dft(DFTimage, Original, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Inverse, -1);

img2.Source = Util.BitmapToImageSource(Original.Bitmap);
img3.Source = Util.BitmapToImageSource(DFTimage.Bitmap);
```

I used a human face, flower, etc but what I see in img2 and img3 (they are Image controls) is black and empty images. What is wrong in my code?

**UPDATE 1:**

Now I'm using this code:

```
Bitmap bm = Util.ImageSourceToBitmap(img1.Source);

Image<Gray, Single> image = new Image<Gray, Single>(bm);
UMat DFTimage = new UMat(image.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 2);
UMat Original = new UMat(image.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 2);


CvInvoke.Dft(image, DFTimage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Forward, image.Rows);
CvInvoke.Dft(Original, DFTimage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Inverse, image.Rows);


Util.BitmapToImageSource(Original.Bitmap);
```

Now I get `System.Exception` exception in showing my inverse image:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   Emgu.CV.World.dll
>
> Additional information: Unknown color type

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
CvInvoke.Dft(Original, DFTimage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Inverse, image.Rows);
```

to this:

```
CvInvoke.Dft(DFTimage, Original, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Inverse, image.Rows);
```